# CSS nth-child: every 4th, 11th, 18th etc

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, children

I have the following div HTML-structure:

- a
- a
- a
- **b**
- **b**
- **b**
- **b**
- a
- a
- a
- **b**
- **b**
- **b**
- **b**

etc.

So, after 3 times a, comes 4 times b. I want to grab every B-element with a css nth-child selector.
I tried nth-child:(4n + 3), but this didn't work out.
Should this be possible with pure css, or do I have to use javascript.

I assume that, if this is possible with css, I would have declare 4 css-selectors.

Thank you!

Comment: Am i correct in thinking you require this to select every 7th starting from the 4th tag?

Comment: @Aaron that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `li:nth-child(7n+4), li:nth-child(7n+5) ...` where `li:nth-child(7n+4)` will match 4, 11, 18... and `li:nth-child(7n+5)` will match 5, 12, 19 etc.

```css
li:nth-child(7n+4), li:nth-child(7n+5), li:nth-child(7n+6), li:nth-child(7n+7) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li>
</ol>
```

You could also use `li:nth-child(7n), li:nth-child(7n-1) ...`

```css
li:nth-child(7n), li:nth-child(7n-1), li:nth-child(7n-2), li:nth-child(7n-3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li><li>Li</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

@NenadVracar's answer is correct, but here's a alternative using [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```css
li:nth-child(7n+4),
li:nth-child(7n+4) + li,
li:nth-child(7n+4) + li + li,
li:nth-child(7n+4) + li + li + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```